# How to pass events of html element with the drop in DND API of HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html

My question is regarding the drag and drop api of html. I want to do it natively but I lose my event handlers after dropping an element. As I don't know how to set all data of my html in 'dataTransfer' object, I am not able to do it.

Basically I was making a list where the list items can be swapped by drag and drop. I made my list item dynamically like this:

```
var div1 = document.createElement("div");//the span element to contain text
var span = document.createElement("span");
//the textnode inside of div1 at starting
var txt1 = document.createTextNode(textdata);
//the option button on div1
var optionBtn = document.createElement("button");
//the option button text
var optionText = document.createTextNode("options");
span.appendChild(txt1);

    div1.appendChild(span);
    optionBtn.appendChild(optionText);
    optionBtn.addEventListener("click",function(){
        console.log("clicked on options")
    });
    div1.appendChild(optionBtn);
    div1.classList.add("draggableDiv");//this div1 is later appended inside my html
```

I put the above code in a function and call this function inside the forEach of an array which consists of 'textdata':

```
var textdatas = ["a","b","c"];
```

What I am doing for DnD is given below. For each list item that I added above, I do this:

```
//element that I am dragging
elem.addEventListener("dragstart",function(e){
        e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);
        dragSrcEl = this;
    });

//element where I am dropping
elem.addEventListener("drop",function(e){
        if (e.stopPropagation) {
            e.stopPropagation(); // Stops some browsers from redirecting.
          }

          if (dragSrcEl != this) { // the dragSrcEl contains the dragging element's data
             dragSrcEl = this.innerHTML;
             this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
          }
    });
```

Now the problem is that I don't know how to pass the events of 'optionBtn'(or any event of any child element) in the 'dataTransfer' of DnD.

Please provide a solution for this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I guess you'd like to use drag and drop to reorder the menu items? Short hints: the draggable element needs a `draggable=true` DOM attribute. IMO, you don't need to store the `dragSrcEl`, because you can inspect the type and data of the drag from that `dataTransfer` object (I understand "inspection" is the reason for the last `if`). You may want to inspect the event's `target` element and store the appropriate data (e.g. the button text/value instead of `innerHTML`). To accept a valid drop target you have to _prevent_ the `dragover` Event default cancelling behaviour.

Comment: Yes I want to reorder menu items but I don't want to lose the event handlers on the buttons inside the menu item after drag. Also I don't want to call a function to attach event handler every time I drag and drop.